# Cover a tag in AMP html structure

Tags: hyperlink, amp-html

I've received the following error in my Google Search consonle

Invalid value of HTML- target in tag 'a'

How can I set up this correctly in a valid AMP-HTML?

Comment: What is the current value you are using for target ?

Comment: well for example: 

<a href="www.google.com">Google</a> 

AMP doesnt allow this and will display an error in Google Search Console. I am wondering how to cover this.

Comment: Some where there is anchor tag with invalid target value. Check all anchors in page using `$$('a')` in browser console

Comment: @StanleyBateswar amp allow target="_new" and target=" _blank", may be there is target="_self"